# Dynamic Search using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

**Table View**

[image: Table view image]

**After Search**

[image: After search image]

When I'm searching the table second column display string with "," as displaying in second table, I'm passing `list<string>` to table any idea how can I solve this ?? This is my jquery search method

Comment: Instead of images you need to provide the code and explain.

Comment: "<td>" + value.Vehicles + "</td>" +                     
Here is my code to set table data , "value.Vehicel" is list string this string break with ",' i won't to break with is newlines any idea

Comment: Please edit your question, do not add your code as comment. Thanks!

Comment: Alternative option is to run the search/filter on the server and return the final HTML directly, then it will always be the same (instead of in 2 places - initial asp.net then javascript for changes)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `value.Vehicles` with `value.Vehicles.split(",").join("<br>")`.